# ASP.NET Web API and IdentityServer issue with CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, identityserver3

I had an MVC controller which was doing *logout* and it was working fine. We decided to migrate from MVC to Web API and translated all the code. Now, on *logout* action I'm getting response error like

> CORS request made for path: **path-to-my-identity-server/login** from
>   origin: **localhost:port** but rejected because invalid CORS path.

It confused me because CORS is enabled on IS by follow

```
factory.CorsPolicyService = 
             new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(
                             new DefaultCorsPolicyService
                             {
                                AllowAll = true
                             });
```

Here an implementation of *logout* action in API controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("logout")]
public void Logout()
{
    HttpContext.Current
        .GetOwinContext()
        .Authentication
        .SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Properties.Settings.Default.SelfUrl,
        });
}
```

and here MVC controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Properties.Settings.Default.SelfUrl,
        });

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I've googled it a lot but no way for me to found the cause. Any help

Comment: Can you confirm  if System.Web.HttpContext or  System.Web.MVC.HttpContext  used in your Web API ?

Comment: @ChethanM System.Web.HttpContext

Comment: You are doing logout, for an API? Not sure if this is a good idea..

Comment: @jpgrassi why not? web api project template suggest such thing out-of-the-box in account controller

Comment: Because usually, APIs shouldn't keep state. Doing login via your API will create sessions. Instead, what's recommended is protected your API with Bearer Tokens. I'm no purist myself and if it works and suit your needs than it's fine. Just pointed that there are other ways. If you want to expose your api to other people, say partners than this does not work anymore.

Comment: @jpgrassi I see your point. Thanks, will keep it in mind but now we should solve it by exactly that way

Comment: Try enabling CORS with this `config.EnableCors();` in WebApiConfig

Comment: See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api